Does two O atoms attached to P in a phosphate group, one as a double bond and other as a single bond make the molecule chiral?
Suppose there is a phosphate group with P attached to 4 groups-
-O-R, -O-R', -O, =O (Last two differs by the bond type: single and double bond)
The P is sp3 hybridised and would be chiral if all 4 groups attached to it are different. Are -O (single bond) and =O (double bond) considered to be different groups by virtue of their difference in bond type?

It is not really sp3 hybridized. The Lewis structure shows five electron pairs associated with the P atom (or you drop the double bond and have a positive formal charge on P and a negative formal charge on two Os).

No. The bonding is delocalized. You are really looking at one contributing structure, and the molecule will also have the mirror-image contribution.
Note that your structure would be an anion $\ce{O2P(OR)(OR')^-}$. A neutral molecule, $\ce{OP(OR)(OR')(OR'')}$ with R, R', R'' all different, would be chiral with all four oxygens attached to different R groups or no R group.
